# Не корректно работает urlopen?

Tags: python, http

> `raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)`
> `HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. )`

?

Comment: Ну так и чего тут некорректного? Здесь же чёрным по белому написано: Proxy Authentication Required

Comment: Прошу прощения, не так сказал, в целом есть proxy server ISA с именем: XXXX port namber: 8080 user: user pass: ***** . как сделать запрос на страничку?

Answer (score 1):

Советую почитать вот здесь: [python/urllib зависает запрос через прокси](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/6369736).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, как рекомендуют в [документации](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html):

```
import urllib

proxies = {'http': 'http://proxy.example.com:8080/'}
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener(proxies)
f = opener.open("http://www.python.org")
f.read()
```